# Remove xsd element when converting xsd to java using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm going to generate java code from the xsd. I want to know how to remove xsd element when converting xsd to java using jaxb. My goal is to ignore message

Ex:

```
<xs:element name="note">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="message"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Java Variables

```
        @XmlElement
        protected String name;
```

In here you can see that message element got removed. I want to know how to do that?

Comment: I think question needs some more context. Are you generating java code from the xsd, or hand coding it? And name in xsd is an XmlElement not an XmlAttribute. What is your goal, is it to ignore message?

Comment: Updated the question please check

Comment: I'm still not sure what the problem is. Can't you just ignore it by never use setMessage() or getMessage()?

Comment: No because i'm using jaxb2-value-constructor to generate constructor because of this it will add additional parameter

Like : 

   Note(String name , String message)

But i want 

   Note(String name);

Comment: Then don't generate constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, to sum it up you want to ignore a mandatory element and still want the result to validate correctly. My short answer is that this is contradictory and does not make sense. JAXB is built to do it correctly and you want do it wrongly(?).

You have several options, eg.

- Live with the extra constructor argument.
- Generate no-arg constructor instead.
- Don't generate, but hand code JAXB annotated classes. Maybe turn off some validation.
- Don't use JAXB, use something else (dom4j et. al.) or handcraft the xml
- Possibly you can add some overriding in a binding file or even a plug-in, but I wouldn't think it was worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you alter the .xsd ?
The current Element "note" tells that both "name" and "message" are mandatory. If you want "message" to be conditional you probably need to add minOccurs="0" attribute:

```
<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="message" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: I can't alter the xsd because i want this to validate the XML. minOccurs="0" is not the solution. I tried it but still can see the "message" property in generated java file

Comment: Why do you want to remove "message" ? If you do so you will not be able to validate the XML as, according to your XSD, all XML should have the "message" tag present.

Comment: In my XML message property use for some other purpose because of that  i can't remove it from xsd and xml . But in here the generated java class should not contain the message property because i'm using jaxb2-value-constructor to generate constructor ant it will add additional parameter Like : Note(String name , String message) But i want Note(String name);

Comment: What I understand is: the XSD tells that "message" element is mandatory and you want to ignore it, just as if it was not in the XSD. Can't you just call the generated constructor with empty string for message ?